# How do I repair a bad update in Fedora 28?(edited)

Tags: command-line, fedora, yum, dnf, software-updates

I was updating my laptop when an electrical blackout happene. I restarted and try to use again `sudo dnf update`, but this happened:

```
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/doc/glibc/INSTALL from install of glibc-2.27-30.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.27-19.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/doc/glibc/NEWS from install of glibc-2.27-30.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.27-19.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/licenses/glibc/LICENSES from install of glibc-2.27-30.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.27-19.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/kpackage/Purpose/Twitter/metadata.json from install of kf5-purpose-twitter-5.48.0-1.fc28.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kf5-purpose-5.47.0-1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/__pycache__/printers.cpython-36.opt-1.pyc from install of libstdc++-8.1.1-5.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-8.1.1-1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/__pycache__/printers.cpython-36.pyc from install of libstdc++-8.1.1-5.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-8.1.1-1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py from install of libstdc++-8.1.1-5.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-8.1.1-1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.pyc from install of libstdc++-8.1.1-5.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-8.1.1-1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.pyo from install of libstdc++-8.1.1-5.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-8.1.1-1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/licenses/libcom_err/NOTICE from install of libcom_err-1.44.2-0.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package libcom_err-1.43.8-2.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/elfutils.mo from install of elfutils-libelf-0.173-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package elfutils-libelf-0.172-2.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/en@boldquot/LC_MESSAGES/elfutils.mo from install of elfutils-libelf-0.173-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package elfutils-libelf-0.172-2.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/en@quot/LC_MESSAGES/elfutils.mo from install of elfutils-libelf-0.173-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package elfutils-libelf-0.172-2.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/elfutils.mo from install of elfutils-libelf-0.173-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package elfutils-libelf-0.172-2.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/elfutils.mo from install of elfutils-libelf-0.173-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package elfutils-libelf-0.172-2.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/elfutils.mo from install of elfutils-libelf-0.173-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package elfutils-libelf-0.172-2.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/elfutils.mo from install of elfutils-libelf-0.173-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package elfutils-libelf-0.172-2.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/cert8.db.5.gz from install of nss-3.38.0-1.0.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package nss-3.37.3-1.1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/cert9.db.5.gz from install of nss-3.38.0-1.0.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package nss-3.37.3-1.1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/key3.db.5.gz from install of nss-3.38.0-1.0.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package nss-3.37.3-1.1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/key4.db.5.gz from install of nss-3.38.0-1.0.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package nss-3.37.3-1.1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/pkcs11.txt.5.gz from install of nss-3.38.0-1.0.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package nss-3.37.3-1.1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man5/secmod.db.5.gz from install of nss-3.38.0-1.0.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package nss-3.37.3-1.1.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/doc/gstreamer1/NEWS from install of gstreamer1-1.14.2-7.gitafb3d1b.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package gstreamer1-1.14.1-7.gitcba2c7d.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/doc/gstreamer1/RELEASE from install of gstreamer1-1.14.2-7.gitafb3d1b.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package gstreamer1-1.14.1-7.gitcba2c7d.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/discover/flatpak-backend.so from install of plasma-discover-flatpak-5.13.3-3.fc28.x86_64 conflicts with file from package plasma-discover-libs-5.12.5.1-3.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/pulseaudio.mo from install of pulseaudio-libs-12.2-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package pulseaudio-libs-11.1-18.fc28.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/pulseaudio.mo from install of pulseaudio-libs-12.2-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package pulseaudio-libs-11.1-18.fc28.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/pulseaudio.mo from install of pulseaudio-libs-12.2-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package pulseaudio-libs-11.1-18.fc28.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/pulseaudio.mo from install of pulseaudio-libs-12.2-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package pulseaudio-libs-11.1-18.fc28.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/pulseaudio.mo from install of pulseaudio-libs-12.2-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package pulseaudio-libs-11.1-18.fc28.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/pulseaudio.mo from install of pulseaudio-libs-12.2-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package pulseaudio-libs-11.1-18.fc28.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/pulseaudio.mo from install of pulseaudio-libs-12.2-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package pulseaudio-libs-11.1-18.fc28.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/pulseaudio.mo from install of pulseaudio-libs-12.2-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package pulseaudio-libs-11.1-18.fc28.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/doc/libpcap/CHANGES from install of libpcap-14:1.9.0-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package libpcap-14:1.8.1-10.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/doc/libpcap/CREDITS from install of libpcap-14:1.9.0-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package libpcap-14:1.8.1-10.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-filter.7.gz from install of libpcap-14:1.9.0-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package libpcap-14:1.8.1-10.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-linktype.7.gz from install of libpcap-14:1.9.0-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package libpcap-14:1.8.1-10.fc28.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-tstamp.7.gz from install of libpcap-14:1.9.0-1.fc28.i686 conflicts with file from package libpcap-14:1.8.1-10.fc28.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

I have tried to read solutions to this and used commands like:`sudo dnf remove --duplicates`, `sudo dnf autoremove`, `sudo dnf update --skip-broken`, `sudo dnf update --refresh --allowerasing`, but none of this works.

Comment: do you really need all those 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit system (the `i686` ones)

Comment: The large majority of software is written in English so if you are looking for help with it you may want to use an English local.

Comment: Please post text as text and not as an image. Also about: *I have tried several commands to clean packages but none of them worked.* that does not tell what you have tried, how, and the exact results you got.

Comment: I have the hunch you are not telling us the whole story. Is this the result of failed 32 to 64 bits migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 64x System, you should not install 32x packages in. Looking to you picture they are starting to create conflicts.

Comment: Well, I solved using "sudo package-cleanup --cleandupes" and thats all. Thanks to everyone.